# Compare 1D and 2D arrays and return values for 2D array when there is a match with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a script where I have a first list of ID's coming from a column of a sheet:

```
var firstArray = [1,5,4,8]
```

Then with my script I'm fetching an API which is returning me a second list of ID's with value associated to them (key-value pair if you want)

```
var secondArray = [[5,"foo"],[6,"bar"],[7,"blaa"]]
```

I want to compare the two arrays and past the values I get from the API in the secondArray in my sheet when ID's are matching.

So the output in my sheet after executing the script will be like this:

```
IDs Values
1
5   foo  
4
8
```

Right now I'm stuck this the following script:

```
  for(var line in firstArray) 
{

 var isMatched = secondArray.indexOf(firstArray[line]); 
 if (isMatched !== -1) 
 {
   //do something
   ss.getRange(line, 3, 1, 1).setValue(valuesFromsecondArray);
 };
}
```

I want to loop through the first array and when there is a match with the second array I want to capture the index from the first array so I can pass the value in the right row in my sheet

Comment: Do you just want to return "foo"? What if there are two or more matches?

Comment: @SimonBreton I suspect you are trying to create what amounts to an SQL JOIN in the hopes of building functionality akin to a relational database. You will eventually discover that whatever script-driven solution you arrive at, it will not be performant nor will it scale well for relatively large datasets (even with the new V8 upgrade). Please read the following article : [Why You Shouldn't Use Google Sheets As A Database](https://medium.com/@eric_koleda/why-you-shouldnt-use-google-sheets-as-a-database-55958ea85d17)

Comment: @TheAddonDepot I probably didn't explain my issue well. This is not this at all. I have two lists of arrays. One is coming from an API, the other from the sheet. And I want to pass some values from the API to the right index in the sheet. I could use a double loop, but that is not very efficient. Let me update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store key, value of the second array:

```js
function compareTest(){
const firstArray = [1,5,4,8];
const secondArray = [[5,"foo"],[6,"bar"],[7,"blaa"]];
const sMap = new Map(secondArray);
const output = firstArray.map(num=>{
  return sMap.has(num) ? [num, sMap.get(num)] : [num, null]
});
console.log(output);
/*SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
.getRange(2, 3, output.length, output[0].length)
.setValues(output);*/
}
compareTest();
```